# Why cursor CSS not working in Gmail?

Tags: php, html, css

My code sends an email to the client contains a button, it's "cursor:pointer" css is not working in gmail....

```
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Body=' <a href="#">
    <button style="border: 1px solid transparent;cursor: pointer;padding: 
    10px 60px;float: right;border-radius: 3px;color: #fff;background-color: 
    #1b84e7;background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#1b84e7 0%,#1515af 
    100%);">Approve Incident</button>
    </a> ';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
```

Comment: Post your css code so that we can check.

Comment: You might need to give us a little more code than that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer that cursor CSS is not supported in Gmail, see this [Email client css support page on Mailchimp](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/).

Comment: Any alternative solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail follows a strict set of guidelines and security measures to prevent potential abuse or misuse of their platform. To maintain a consistent user experience and protect users from potential security risks, Gmail restricts the use of certain HTML and CSS properties in emails, and the cursor property is one of them.

Therefore, if you're referring to modifying the cursor property in the context of an email template or HTML email, it's important to note that Gmail may not support it. It's always a good practice to test your email templates across various email clients and webmail services to ensure consistent rendering and functionality.

You can also check all the css support elements, https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Gmail supports only subset of css properties. Cursor is not one of them. Here is the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css#supported_css).

Answer (score -1):

Use anchor tag at place of button.

```
 <a href="#" style="border: 1px solid transparent;cursor: pointer;padding: 
    10px 60px;float: right;border-radius: 3px;color: #fff;background-color: 
    #1b84e7;background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#1b84e7 0%,#1515af 
    100%);">Approve Incident
    </a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).